# Linking multiple .c files

Tags: c, linker, makefile

I have a C file named first.c in which I define an array and call a function which is defined in a C file named second.c. This is how first.c looks:

```
int main(void)
{
    int array[100];
    myFunc(*array);
}
```

second.c on the other hand looks like this:

```
void myFunc(int array)
{
    ...
}
```

But anytime I try to compile these, second.c gives me errors as if it had no idea about the array I passed to its function as an argument. I guess the function doesn't know that at the linking stage. I compile these like this:

```
gcc -O2 -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic -lm second.c -c
gcc -O2 -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic first.c -c
gcc second.o first.o -o finished
```

But that's just what I came up with and of course it doesn't work. I guess a Makefile would be in place, but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue may lie in that the received value is not a pointer- so change void `myFunc(int array)` to `void myFunc(int* array)`.

Comment: Great, that fixed the problem. But if I want to keep the `void myFunc(int array)`, what should I pass to the function from first.c?

Comment: @imre You should try `myFunc(array);` **But do not do this**. There is a reason that `array` is passed as a pointer, not the entire object. If the argument is not a pointer, then you are copying the entire array, which is not what you want.

Comment: when I do this, gcc gives me this error on multiple lines: `error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector`, so I guess I should do it your way.

Comment: @imre Don't replace the function declaration with `myFunc(array);`, call `myFunc` like this: `myFunc(array);`.

Comment: This is the function declaration: `void myFunc(int pole);`, I call it with `myFunc(pole);`

Comment: @imre Yup! That looks okay to me

Comment: Well, gcc doesn't like it. Beats me.

Comment: @imre Whoops! Actually, the way that I suggested in the comments won't work because arrays are inherently pointers. Sorry about that.